# como aumentar heigth en div para bajar el footer en resolucion tablet y deskopt?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

El layout por ahora me funciona bien pero en la sección Descargas.php el footer es como 3 veces más alto, por que el contenido principal es poco texto.

le he añadido la clase con-des al primer contenedor con un height 600px / 70%
pero no consigo bajar el footer.

```
<?php include "includes/header.php" ?>

    <div class="container con-des">

    <h1>Descargas</h1>
        <div class="content-descargas">
        <ul class="uldescarga">

            <li class="lidescarga"><img title="descargar" class="icondescarga" src="images/icondownload2.png"><a class="enlacedescarga" href="#">Se busca banda</a>     </li>
            <li class="lidescarga"><img title="descargar" class="icondescarga" src="images/icondownload2.png"><a class="enlacedescarga" href="#">La democracia ha muerto vol 1</a>  </li>
            <li class="lidescarga"><img title="descargar" class="icondescarga" src="images/icondownload2.png"><a class="enlacedescarga" href="#">La democracia ha muerto vol 2</a>      </li>
            <li class="lidescarga"><img title="descargar" class="icondescarga" src="images/icondownload2.png"><a class="enlacedescarga" href="#">Bokerones muertos</a>      </li>
            <li class="lidescarga"><img title="descargar" class="icondescarga" src="images/icondownload2.png"><a class="enlacedescarga" href="#">La desvirtualización de las ideas</a>      </li>   

        </ul>       
        <p>* Las descargas son gratuitas</p>
        </div><!--content-descargas -->
    </div><!--container -->         
        <div class="container">


            <div class="redessociales">
                <ul>
                    <li class="ulsociales"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/JAM%C3%93N-DE-MONO/626328110714565?fref=ts"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a></li>
                    <li class="ulsociales"><a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/ferdelapola"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a></li>
                    <li class="ulsociales"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/user/rockcannabico?feature=watch"><img src="images/youtube.png"></a></li>
                </ul>   

            </div><!--redessociales --> 

    </div><!--container -->



<?php include "includes/footer.php" ?>

/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { 

    .imglogo
    {
             margin-left: 95px;
    }

    .con-desc
    {
        height: 77%;
    }


}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { 

 }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {

.con-desc
    {
        height: 600px;
    }

.content-descargas
{
    height: 700px;
}

 }
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
<head>  
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon-32x32.png" />
    <title>Jamón de mono</title>

</head>

<body>
<header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">


<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 logodiv">
  <img class="imglogo" src="images/logo5.png" alt="">

</div> 


<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- El logotipo y el icono que despliega el menú se agrupan
       para mostrarlos mejor en los dispositivos móviles -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Desplegar navegación</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

  </div>

  <!-- Agrupar los enlaces de navegación, los formularios y cualquier
       otro elemento que se pueda ocultar al minimizar la barra -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="linkmenu active"><a href="index.php">Biografía</a></li>
      <li class="linkmenu"><a href="discografia.php">Discografía</a></li>
      <li class="linkmenu"><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
      <li class="linkmenu"><a href="descargas.php">Descargas</a></li>

  </div>
</nav>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</header>
```

footer.php

```
<footer>

<div class="container">

            <div class="footercontent">
                <p class="parrafofooter"> <?php echo date("Y",time()); ?> &copy; Jamón de mono  </p> 

                <p class="parrafofooter">Teléfono:  665 13 39 56 contacto@jamondemono.com</p>

                <p class="parrafofooter"><a class="cookie" href="#">Política de cookies</a></p>

            </div>





</div> <!-- .container -->          
</footer>
<div id="barraaceptacion">
                <div class="inner">
                    <p>Este sitio web usa Cookies de terceros con el fin de que tenga una mejor experiencia de usuario. Al seguir navegando asumimos que está de acuerdo con ellas.<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ok" onclick="ocultar();">OK</a> 
                    <a class="enlacefooter" href="#"  class="info">Más información</a>

                </div>
            </div>  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
<script>

var clic = 1;

function ocultar()
{ 
   if(clic==1)
   {
       document.getElementById("barraaceptacion").style.display = "none";
      // clic = clic + 1;
   }
   else
   {
      // document.getElementById("caja").style.height = "0px";      
        //clic = 1;
   }   
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Has intentado con position absolute? Sin conocer el contenido de header o footer es muy difícil saber que consejo darte. También podrías crear un jsbin o codepen para saber como es la página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
.con-des {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

vh(viewport height) es una unidad de medida en css, que es con respecto al height del dispositivo

Comment: No va el height: 100vh; sigue igual

Comment: @Rafahernandez intenta poner ese estilo a los tags padres(body, u otro contenedor de todo)

Comment: le he puesto eso al body y no cambia nada

Comment: @Rafahernandez habría que inspeccionar el código, podrias subirlo a un dominio?

Comment: he puesto el height: 23vh; modificando la clase .container de bootstrap y ya me coge el height.

Comment: pero ahora en otras secciones me descuadra gran parte del layout

Comment: @Rafahernandez por el momento crea una clase solamente para este layout  .con-des-perzonalizado por ejemplo

Comment: solucionado de momento he creado una clase nueva y solo afecta ya a descargas.php no al resto

Comment: @Rafahernandez perfecto, seria bueno poder tu código en un dominio , porque el tener que haber puesto 23vh no es normal

Comment: www.jamondemono.com/mono

Comment: @Rafahernandez, es este el link donde el contenido es poco y el footer se sube??

Comment: si ese es. en descargas. ahora el height: 47vh; lo tengo asi.

Comment: @Rafahernandez, amigo perdon, si esta bien el vh aplicado, te entendi que te estabas pasando de los 100vh y no es así, por otro lado, es correcto aplicar una clase personalizada para estos layout que no tienen mucho contenido